# Return all change lists submitted by a specified User - Perforce Java API

Tags: java, api, perforce, changelist

I am currently trying to write a method using the [perforce java API](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4java-javadoc/) to return all submitted changelists by a specified user. The trouble is I can't seem to find any methods in the API which could help me.

Would I be right in saying that I would have to use something like this?

```
List<IFileSpec> userFiles = iServer.getDepotFiles(FileSpecBuilder.makeFileSpecList(new String[] {"//...@"+userName}), false);
```

Any advice would be appreciated !!

**Edit**

Or would it be something along these [lines](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r10.1/manuals/p4java-javadoc/com/perforce/p4java/server/IOptionsServer.html#getChangelists%28java.util.List,%20com.perforce.p4java.option.server.GetChangelistsOptions%29)

Comment: I think that GetChangelists() is the way to go. Your options can specify that you only want submitted changelists, and only by a specified user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer seemed to be already answered by you and Bryan Pendleton.

For those looking for a straight answer:

`getChangelists()` as documented [here](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r10.1/manuals/p4java-javadoc/com/perforce/p4java/server/IOptionsServer.html#getChangelists%28java.util.List,%20com.perforce.p4java.option.server.GetChangelistsOptions%29), is the method to you. To filter the results, provide a `GetChangelistsOptions` that specifies which values you want to filter on, in this case, `userName`